# How to make a correct flow working with JWT Access Token and JWT Refresh Token?

Tags: jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I'm building an app which for authorization and authentication use Access Token and Refresh Token, and I would like to ask if I'm doing this correctly.

I've read that sending Access Tokens via HTTP is vulnerable to attacks in the transport layer, but saving them in the browser's memory poses an easy theft risk. Therefore, I'm considering combining both methods in the following flow: [Click for see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr4N4.jpg)

**My question is: The flow in the image is correct?**

The most important point is:

**1.** Send only the Access Token in a cookie http only, but send the Refresh Token in a JSON response (so later the client can save it in the session storage). This is because if I send both in different cookies, both will be used in each request, which doesn't make sense because the main purpose of the Refresh Token is to be used as infrequently as possible.
Getting the Refresh Token from JSON response and saving it in the session storage I will be able to choose which request to use it in.

Basically from what I understood so far, whatever method you choose, cookie or local/session storage, the token is at risk of being stolen, but the benefit of using the access token and the refresh token is the ability to constantly renew them reducing the time of use in case of being stolen.

So, this was the most suitable method I thought.

I'd like to know if it's a good approach, and also if I'm understanding the concepts correctly, because it's very likely that I've missed something. Thank you for reading.

Comment: if you are concerned about token theft bind them to a connection characteristic (say ip address). so in case of theft, it will only be valid if used from the same network. the downside here is that with mobile clients the networks change frequently and this will invalidate the tokens. but still, security comes at a price.

Comment: @mrmcwolf yes, I thought about also adding all those security details, such as the ip address and the user-agent, but first I would like to know if implementing the access token with the refresh token as I showed in the image would be correct

Comment: @mrmcwolf sorry for the delay, I wanted to ask you, what can I do if the IP address is dynamic? Is there a way to use another feature that is always fixed?

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamic", dhcp? you don't care what the address itself is, the important thing is that it doesn't change during the session because that will invalidate the token. there is an option to use some characteristic of the client (OS version, browser and display type to be taken with javascript). (if you're doing something where security is really important, use certificates for authentication)

Comment: @mrmcwolf yes, I refer to dhcp. Ok, thanks. So, the ip is used once the user log in for save it in somewhere (database for example), and if someone stolen the token and used, the system will detect that their ip don't match with the IP of the actived session and will invalidate the token?